# Convergence of eigenmodes of a Sturm Liouville operator.

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

Is there any "eassy to see" proof for:

"The eigenmodes of a Sturm Liouville ODE in a closed  interval [a,b], with given boundary conditions, form a complete, orthogonal basis for continuous functions defined in [a,b] meeting the same boundary conditions."???

I found some references, but they seem to be somewhat obscure. I've been trying to get my own proof but I keep hitting the wall.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "easy to see"? Also tell us which references you didn't like so that we can recommend others.

Comment: Sure. I checked "Mathematical Methods for Physicists" by Arfken and Weber, "Fourier Sernies and Orthogonal Functions" by Harry Davis and other Fourier series and Orthogonal polynomials books. Also "Sturm-Liouville Theory, past and present..." edited by Amrein and others. Some of the references just mention the completeness, and the last reference has something too high for me. "Easy to see" would mean "at undergrad level" maybe. Should I go on and edit the question? Thanks.

Comment: See $\S1.2$ of http://math.sgu.ru/users/yurko/publications/novabook.pdf‎, for instance.

Comment: Sorry, the link does not seem to work. Can you send it again please?

Comment: I just checked it again, it works. Try later or may be you should use a proxy.

Comment: Got it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is no need to restrict to functions satisfying the same endpoint conditions. The orthogonal functions always form a complete orthogonal set. Of course, if all the orthonormal functions $\{ e_{n}\}$ satisfy $e_{n}(a)=0$, then you won't get pointwise convergence for $f=\sum_{n}(f,e_{n})e_{n}$ at $a$, but you can get it everywhere else on $(a,b)$ if the function is, for example, differentiable. Regardless, you'll always get convergence in $L^{2}_{w}[a,b]$ with respect to the proper weight $w$, and the eigenfunctions will form a complete orthonormal basis of $L^{2}_{w}[a,b]$. Moreover, for such regular problems $Ly=-(py')y'+qy$, it is possible (under reasonable conditions on the coefficients) to change variables to get an equivalent problem $L_{new}y=-y''+Qy$. In this transformed setting, one can show that the convergence of expansions is equivalent to the convergence of classical expansions where $Q=0$ (keeping the same endpoint conditions, of course.) This equivalence is strong: the Fourier series with $Q \ne 0$ converges at some point $x$ iff the series for the problem where $Q=0$ converges at the same point and, when either converges at $x$, they both converge to the same value. It turns out that the eigenfunctions $y''+Qy=\lambda y$ are asymptotically like those of $y''=\lambda y$ for large $|\lambda|$, and this approximation is very good, so good that the eigenvalues of the general problem can be shown to be asymptotic to those where $Q=0$ as the eigenvalues tend to $\infty$. This is why special functions on non-singular intervals always have familiar asymptotics, too.